# Unable to upload file to server

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-core

Good day, there is a client-server project, a client on the hangar, a server on the bark. On the server, the file download code:

```
[HttpPost("[action]/{formData}"), Route("addfile")]
    public async Task AddFile(IFormFile formData)
    {


            string path = "/Files/" + formData.FileName;

            using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_appEnvironment.WebRootPath + path, FileMode.Create))
            {
                await formData.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
            }
            FileModel file = new FileModel { Name = formData.FileName, Path = path };
            db.Files.Add(file);
            db.SaveChanges();

    }
```

on the client: Component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpEventType } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'add-file',
  templateUrl: './add-files.component.html',

})

export class AddFilesComponent implements OnInit {

  fileData: File = null;
  previewUrl: any = null;
  fileUploadProgress: string = null;
  uploadedFilePath: string = null;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  fileProgress(fileInput: any) {
    this.fileData = <File>fileInput.target.files[0];
    this.preview();
  }

  preview() {
    // Show preview 
    var mimeType = this.fileData.type;
    if (mimeType.match(/image\/*/) == null) {
      return;
    }

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.fileData);
    reader.onload = (_event) => {
      this.previewUrl = reader.result;
    }
  }

  onSubmit() {
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('files', this.fileData);

    this.fileUploadProgress = '0%';

    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/api/file/addfile', formData, {
      reportProgress: true,
      observe: 'events'
    })
      .subscribe(events => {
        if (events.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
          this.fileUploadProgress = Math.round(events.loaded / events.total * 100) + '%';
          console.log(this.fileUploadProgress);
        } else if (events.type === HttpEventType.Response) {
          this.fileUploadProgress = '';
          console.log(events.body);
          alert('SUCCESS !!');
        }

      }) 
  }
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-3">
      <h3>Choose File</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="image" (change)="fileProgress($event)" />
      </div>
      <div *ngIf="fileUploadProgress">
        Upload progress: {{ fileUploadProgress }}
      </div>
      <div class="image-preview mb-3" *ngIf="previewUrl">
        <img [src]="previewUrl" height="300" />
      </div>

      <div class="mb-3" *ngIf="uploadedFilePath">
        {{uploadedFilePath}}
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="onSubmit()">Submit</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note: If you implement everything only in the cortex, then everything works, the file is loaded, so everything is in order with the code. The problem is that the file does not come from the server, it passes a breakpoint on the client, the file is sent, I put a breakpoint on the server, I start everything in a new way, there is a reaction, that is, the client starts the method on the server, however I see that `IFormFile formData` is null, which means that there’s nothing to save .. I feel that I’ve made a mistake in the little things, poke where pls ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are required to change parameter's name to correspond `files`,change your action to

```
[HttpPost("[action]"), Route("addfile")]
public async Task AddFile([FromForm]IFormFile files)
```

Comment: @D2 Life Could you [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if you have resolved the problem?